# What is the purpose of (void)variable in C?

Tags: c, embedded

I am reading [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-STM32-Developing-FreeRTOS-libopencm3/dp/1484236238) and I have come across this code:

```
static void
task1(void *args) {
    int i;

    (void)args;

    for (;;) {
        gpio_toggle(GPIOC,GPIO13);
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            __asm__("nop");
    }
}
```

I understand all (relatively) except for line 5. What is `(void)args;` doing?

`args` is not used in the function body, and I know that if an argument is not used then one could write

```
static void
task2(void *args __attribute((unused))) {
     // code here
}
```

which is not being done here. So what is `(void)` written like that doing?

Comment: Oddly, none of the answers explicitly state what the `(void)` in `(void) args;` is doing. It is a cast, similar to `(int) 3.5`, which converts 3.5 to an `int`, or `(char *) &x`, which converts the address of `x` to a pointer to `char`. Nominally, `(void) args;` converts the value of `args` to the type `void`. Since `void` has no values, the conversion produces no value. After that, the answers here and at the original apply: It is a way of telling the compiler you are deliberately ignoring `args`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general when one does not use an function argument, the compiler is likely to warn you about it. After all if you aren't going to use it why put it there in the first place?

In effect it is an artificial use of the argument that does nothing useful other than telling the compiler you know what you are doing, so "*Shatupalready with the warning*!"

**(void) args** works on all of the platforms that I have seen.   I believe the **__attribute((unused)**) is a gcc specific thing.

Answer (score 3):

Every expression has a type. Any expression can be turned into a statement by adding a semicolon. If an *expression-statement* yields a non-`void` value, that value is discarded.

Compilers will often warn about a value being discarded. Even a simple case like

```
printf("hello world\n");
```

quietly discards the `int` value returned by `printf`; a compiler warning might remind the programmer to test that value and take some action if it indicates that the call failed. (Most compilers will not warn in this particular case, since `printf` calls are *usually* used in a statement context, with the result ignored.)

Casting an expression to type `void` discards the result, but it does so explicitly. This is likely to silence a compiler warning.

As far as the language is concerned, a `(void)` cast converts a result to type `void`, which is equivalent to discarding that result. From a programmer's point of view, a `(void)` cast can silence a warning that a value is not used, since you're *explicitly* ignoring it and asserting to the compiler that you know what you're doing (even if you don't).

Quoting the C standard ([N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), 6.3.2.2:

> The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has
>   type **`void`**) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or
>   explicit conversions (except to **`void`**) shall not be applied to
>   such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as
>   a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void
>   expression is evaluated for its side effects.)

and 6.2.5 paragraph 19:

> The **`void`** type comprises an empty set of values; it is an
>   incomplete object type that cannot be completed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler warning (`-W unused-variable` or `-W all`) they're suppressing by using it. You are correct in that `__attribute__((unused))` is a valid C macro to do what you're asking, but it's a matter of preference. It's also not supported by all C compilers.

Sources:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124983230.htm
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Answer (score 1):

`void` is an empty data type, it can be used in a different number of situations.

A function that "returns" `void` doesn't return anything (and by definition is a procedure, not a function).

A `void*` (pointer of `void`) is often used as a generic pointer (a pointer to a memory address with no particular data type associated with it). The compiler will let you assign this pointer to any other pointer type without need of explicit conversion.

`malloc()` for example, returns `void*` so you can do things like `int* v = malloc(sizeof(int)*10));` without need of explicitly recasting the return value of `malloc()` to `int*`.

The other way around is also true, a function that takes `void*` as parameter will take any pointer type without need of explicit conversion.